# Rearrange string in Python according to whole number first, then increasing values of groups

Tags: python, regex, string, list, sorting

For example, consider the string `'3a+1+4c+3b'`. Then, using some regex, you split that into `['3a','1','4c','3b']`. **How could I rearrange that list so that it is sorted such that the number without a letter following is put first in the list, then the rest of the elements are sorted in the  in increasing values of number/letter combinations?** For example, `['3a','1','4c','3b']` becomes `['1','3a','3b','4c']`.

**Edit:**

So, just to clarify, I did use `sorted`, but if I use it, for example, on `2k+1-6j+9i`, which turns into `['1', '2k', '6j', '9i']`, as you can seem it is not sorted in order of increasing letter value. I want it to instead be `['1','9i','6j','3k']`.

Comment: just `sorted` works for your example.  can you give a better example?

Comment: `natsorted(s.split('+'))` using [natsort](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/natsort) package.

Comment: @zondo will break for integers higher than 9

Comment: Will the data contain integers higher than 9, then?

Comment: http://ideone.com/QJfQSF

Comment: My guess would be that the intention of the question is for `['3a','5','4c','2b']` to become sorted to `['5','3a','2b','4c']`. I.e., sorting by the letter suffix, not by the integral value.

Comment: @SebastianPaaskeTørholm Yes, you are correct.

Comment: @R.Kap Perfect. I figured it'd be something like quaternions.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a key for `sorted()`:

```
>>> sorted(['3a','5','4c','2b'], key=lambda x: (not x.isdigit(), x[::-1]))
['5', '3a', '2b', '4c']
```

Note, though, that it might not work how you expect it to if your strings are more than two characters long.  You might do something like this:

```
sorted([...], key=lambda x: (not x.isdigit(), x[-1], int(x[:-1]) if x[:-1] else int(x)))
```

Comment: What does  `(len(x),x[::-1])` actually do in the `lambda` function actually do?

Comment: @R.Kap: I have changed it slightly, but it returns a tuple of whether or not the string is a number and the reverse of the string.  If the string is a number, the tuple would be `(0, reversed_string)`, but if it isn't, it is `(1, reversed_string)`.  Since tuples with a lower value come first, a string that is just a number will come before a string that is not.  Using the reversed string as the second argument puts the last character, the letter, as of more importance than the others.

Answer (score 0):

Sort it with a key that returns a `tuple` containing the first priority - whether the element isn't all digits - followed by the second priority - the letters in the element - followed by the possible third priority - the integer value of the numbers in the element.

```
def sorter(l):
    return sorted(l, key=lambda x: (not x.isdigit(),
                                    ''.join(filter(str.isalpha, x)),
                                    int(''.join(filter(str.isdigit, x)))))
```

Results:

```
>>> sorter(['3a','1','4c','3b'])
['1', '3a', '3b', '4c']
>>> sorter(['1231212', '1a'])
['1231212', '1a']
>>> sorter(['13a', '3a'])
['3a', '13a']
```